# Patch Management Operations Plan

Tags: windows-update, wsus, patch-management

I'm developing a plan/strategy to manage patch deployment on Windows Clients using Windows Server Update Services. What are the some important things to consider in developing this plan? For example, *auto-rebooting after an update* although may seem trivial, may have considerable impact on some machines. So one solution is, to create a separate patch group in WSUS for machines that shouldn't auto-reboot. Tell me some things to keep in mind when developing a patch management plan and how to solve them. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We stay a month behind (it's a nice round number) and also keep a separate group for machines that shouldn't auto-reboot.  We also make a specific effort to *exclude* service packs, new versions of IE, and other major upgrades from the patch management system, taking the view that as these constitute a major upgrade you want to be physically there to see it happening, and respond to anything that needs responding to.

You should certainly consider having a test group of PCs that are a good representation of what's out there that *don't* stay a month behind (i.e. get their patches immediately).  That way, if a patch is going to cause trouble at the PC level, you will find out about it quickly enough and can make a call on how to deal with it without every PC being affected.

Finally, in WSUS "update rollups" is a category separate to "critical and security updates", but yet some vital recent patches (Conficker, anyone?) were classified under that heading, so ensure that you don't miss it!

Answer (score 1):

Have a solid plan to revert back.  I would say just uninstalling the patch is not a good enough plan.  So really this needs to be integrated into your backup plan.

Also, if you think your security can afford it, you might considering being a couple weeks behind.  This will give you a chance to read about the patch before applying it, to see if caused issues with any of your applications.

Answer (score 1):

For our WSUS server, I created OUs for the workstations, then below that I split it up into regions in the office. We also have one for laptops and member servers and domain controllers. I then created different views of the updates to suite my needs for example, I have a SQL Server update category, and Office category and a 2003 category and a... Sure it gets to the point where I might have too many, but it keeps it easy to read. So if there is a bad patch out there, I don't click approve on accident because I was shift-clicking.

Plus in the long run, I think it'll be easier to keep track of all the patching that is done.